# Como retirar elementos negativos de uma fila?

Tags: c

Boa Tarde galera,

Estou tentando retirar um elemento negativo de uma fila, conseguimos colocar os elementos na fila porém na hora de retirar o elemento ele retira sempre o primeiro elemento...

Esse é o Exercício passado pela professora:
Dada uma fila de inteiros, escreva um programa que exclua todos os números
negativos sem alterar a posição dos outros elementos da fila.

Esse é o código que implementamos:
Insere elemento na Fila:

```
void insere(node *FILA)
{
    node *novo=aloca();
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if(vazia(FILA))
        FILA->prox=novo;
    else{
        node *tmp = FILA->prox;

        while(tmp->prox != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->prox;

        tmp->prox = novo;
    }
    tam++;
}
```

Retira elemento negativo da pilha (Esse que está com problemas):

```
void excluiNegativos(node *FILA)
{
    if(vazia(FILA)){
        printf("Fila vazia!\n\n");
        return ;
    }

    node *tmp;
    tmp = FILA->prox;
    while( tmp != NULL){
        if(tmp->num<0){
            tmp->num = "";
        }
        tmp = tmp->prox;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

O Inserir elementos na fila está perfeito, porém o excluir elementos da fila está bugando...

Obrigado desde já!

Código completo, compile usando a opção para inserir e depois use a opção para remover números inteiros negativos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int num;
    struct Node *prox;
};
typedef struct Node node;

int tam;

int menu(void);
void opcao(node *FILA, int op);
void inicia(node *FILA);
int vazia(node *FILA);
node *aloca();
void insere(node *FILA);
node *retira(node *FILA);
void exibe(node *FILA);
void libera(node *FILA);
void excluiNegativos(node *FILA);
void somaFilas(node *FILA, node *FILA2);


int main(void)
{
    node *FILA = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!FILA){
        printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
    inicia(FILA);
    int opt;

    do{
        opt=menu();
        opcao(FILA,opt);
    }while(opt);

    free(FILA);
    return 0;
    }
}


int menu(void)
{
    int opt;

    printf("Escolha a opcao\n");
    printf("0. Sair\n");
    printf("1. Zerar fila\n");
    printf("2. Exibir fila\n");
    printf("3. Adicionar Elemento na Fila\n");
    printf("4. Retirar Elemento da Fila\n");
    printf("5. Retirar Elemento Negativos da Fila\n");
    printf("6. Somar 2 filas ordenadas\n");
    printf("Opcao: "); scanf("%d", &opt);

    return opt;
}

void opcao(node *FILA, int op)
{
    node *tmp;
    switch(op){
        case 0:
            libera(FILA);
            break;

        case 1:
            libera(FILA);
            inicia(FILA);
            break;

        case 2:
            exibe(FILA);
            break;

        case 3:
            insere(FILA);
            break;

        case 4:
            tmp= retira(FILA);
            if(tmp != NULL){
                printf("Retirado: %3d\n\n", tmp->num);
                libera(tmp);
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            tmp= retira(FILA);
            if(tmp != NULL){
                excluiNegativos(tmp);
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Digite os elementos da fila. Digite 0 para sair \n");
            int aux;
            node *tmp1;
            node *tmp2;
            inicia(tmp1);
            scanf("%d", &aux);
            while(aux!=0){
                insere(tmp1);
            }
            inicia(tmp2);
            scanf("%d", &aux);
            while(aux!=0){
                insere(tmp2);
            }
            somaFilas(tmp1, tmp2);
            break;  

        default:
            printf("Comando invalido\n\n");
    }
}

void inicia(node *FILA)
{
    FILA->prox = NULL;
    tam=0;
}

int vazia(node *FILA)
{
    if(FILA->prox == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

node *aloca()
{
    node *novo=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!novo){
        printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("Novo elemento: "); scanf("%d", &novo->num);
        return novo;
    }
}

void insere(node *FILA)
{
    node *novo=aloca();
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if(vazia(FILA))
        FILA->prox=novo;
    else{
        node *tmp = FILA->prox;

        while(tmp->prox != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->prox;

        tmp->prox = novo;
    }
    tam++;
}


node *retira(node *FILA)
{
    if(FILA->prox == NULL){
        printf("Fila ja esta vazia\n");
        return NULL;
    }else{
        node *tmp = FILA->prox;
        FILA->prox = tmp->prox;
        tam--;
        return tmp;
    }

}


void exibe(node *FILA)
{
    if(vazia(FILA)){
        printf("Fila vazia!\n\n");
        return ;
    }

    node *tmp;
    tmp = FILA->prox;
    printf("Fila :");
    while( tmp != NULL){
        printf("%5d", tmp->num);
        tmp = tmp->prox;
    }
    printf("\n        ");
    int count;
    for(count=0 ; count < tam ; count++)
        printf("  ^  ");
    printf("\nOrdem:");
    for(count=0 ; count < tam ; count++)
        printf("%5d", count+1);


    printf("\n\n");
}

void libera(node *FILA)
{
    if(!vazia(FILA)){
        node *proxNode,
              *atual;

        atual = FILA->prox;
        while(atual != NULL){
            proxNode = atual->prox;
            free(atual);
            atual = proxNode;
        }
    }
}
void excluiNegativos(node *FILA)
{
    if(vazia(FILA)){
        printf("Fila vazia!\n\n");
        return ;
    }

    node *tmp;
    tmp = FILA->prox;
    while( tmp != NULL){
        if(tmp->num<0){
            tmp->num = "";
        }
        tmp = tmp->prox;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
void somaFilas (node tmp1, node tmp2){

}
```

Comment: E qual é o *bug*? Qual a estrutura do nó?

Comment: Está excluindo sempre o primeiro da fila e não todos os negativos, estamos inserindo com lista....

Comment: Como você sabe qual é o primeiro? Vou pedir mais uma vez. Coloque a estrutura do nó. Pra mim a inserção está errada. Sem ver esse código funcionando, acho que não dá para responder isto. Acho que ele tem outro problemas.

Comment: Pronto, editei e coloquei o código completo que estou usando.

Comment: O código nem compila. Pode ser que esteja compilando para você porque quem não conhece bem o compilador e o processo de desenvolvimento, acaba deixando passar erros, mas se compilar mandando ver todos os erros, não compila. Consertei alguns erros, mas vai aparecendo outros, alguns bem básicos. Não dá para mexer nisto.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer de outra forma e melhorar meu entendimento sobre o código e os erros, assim q eu souber melhor envio editado a pergunta novamente... Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Uma coisa importante, isto é uma fila ou uma lista ligada? O nome usado é fila, mas ela não parece ser fila. As nomenclaturas não são de fila. Onde a fila começa e termina? Essa informação não está no código e não tem como gerenciar uma fila sem estas informações. Eu li o código com mais atenção e não faz o que está afirmando na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lógica para remover um elemento durante a pesquisa na fila é manter um ponteiro para o elemento anterior, pois é o elemento anterior que tem que ser alterado ao se remover o elemento corrente da fila. Por exemplo, se o elemento corrente, que deve ser removido (porque é negativo, mas poderia ser qualquer outra condição), é apontado por "tmp", você precisa apontar o elemento anterior à "tmp" para o elemento seguinte a "tmp".

Lembre-se que existe uma situação especial que é quando existir apenas um elemento na fila. Neste caso não há elemento anterior e deve-se atualizar o cabeçalho da fila.

Também é necessário desalocar da memória o elemento removido ou guardá-lo para fazer alguma coisa com ele posteriormente.

O pseudo-código é o seguinte:

```
node* anterior = FILA;
node* corrente = anterior->prox;
while (corrente != NULL) {
    if (corrente->num < 0) {
        node* tmp = corrente;
        anterior->prox = corrente->prox;
        corrente = corrente->prox;
        /* fazer algo com o nó em tmp - possivelmente free(tmp) */
    }
    else {
        anterior = corrente;
        corrente = corrente->prox;
    }
}
```

Boa sorte!